# Problemas con WordPress y hostinger

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, hosting

tengo un problema, recien empiezo con wordpress, no me gusta mucho la verdad, pero debo hacerlo. Hice una pagina en local, con la base de datos en local también. Todo bien hasta ahi. Pero, cuando quiero cambiar la conexion a una base de datos en el hosting empiezan los problemas. Me crea las bases de datos (Cosa que indica que la conexion es correcta y que el servidor esta funcionando), pero, al colocar el nombre de usuario y contraseña (momento donde deberia guardar estos datos en la bd del hosting), no lo hace, al contrario, me patea con un error "El sitio está experimentando dificultades técnicas.". Cosa que me trae mal desde hace 2 dias, ayuda por favor, ya corrobore la conexion y todo bien, no he tocado nada porque en este caso, empece uno nuevo para ver que onda despues del local. Alguien me daria una mano?

Answer (score 0):

lo que te voy entendiendo es que hiciste la web en local y a la hora de migrar al servidor estas tendiendo problemas, es muy común estos problemas ya que muchas cosas cambian de local al servidor, entre estas cosas: cambios en la conexión de la bd, las ulrs son diferentes etc, para corregir el problema de acceso puedes cambiar el correo de recuperación en la tabla de opciones de mysql en el servidor(la bd que creaste para la migración de wordpress) y por ahí lo podrías restablecer, me cuentas que más problemas tienes.